# Recursive Promise Call- Memory Scope Variable Issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

I have these functions for the purpose of retrieving a token through a api call out. If the user enters the wrong password, the promise will reject and on reject the function is called again to give the user another try.

If the user enters the right password the first time, there is no issue.

But if the user enters a wrong password and tries again...but tries again successfully, I am having a memory issue. Because of the recursive call to `callApiToken()` on the second try the promise is fullfilled and  `callApiToken().then(function() { refreshToken(); })` is called.  `file.token = JSON.parse(tokenString);` is completed but in a different memory scope. Not sure what to do about this. I say this because the routine runs successfully. But the global `var file` is not populated as it should be.

`createTokenFile()` is called first.

```
var file = {};

function createTokenFile() {
    block = true;
    callApiToken()
        .then(function() { refreshToken(); }) // ON THE SECOND RECURSIVE     
        .catch(function() {                  // RUN refreshToken() IS CALLED
            callApiToken();
        }).finally(function() {
            block = false;
        });
}

function refreshToken() {
    var tokenFileAbsolute = path.join(__dirname, 'token-file.json');
    return fs.readFileAsync(tokenFileAbsolute, {encoding: 'utf-8'})
        .then(function(tokenString) {
            file.token = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("No token-file.json file found. " .red +
                "Please complete for a new one." .red);
            createTokenFile();
        });
}
```

**UPDATE** with other promise code that gives resolve for `callApiToken()`which is actually `getCredentials`:

Note: `fs.writeFileAsync(tokenFile, token)` does complete successfully on the second recursive call.

```
function getPassword(user) {
    return readAsync({prompt: "Password: ", silent: true, replace: "*" })
        .then(function(pass) {
            return postAsync(URL, payload(user[0], pass[0]));
        });
}
function getCredentials() {
    return readAsync({prompt: "Username: "}).then(getPassword);
}

function writeToFile(data, response) {
    tokenFile =  path.join(__dirname, 'token-file.json');
    token = JSON.stringify({
        id: data.access.token.id,
        expires: data.access.token.expires
    });
    return fs.writeFileAsync(tokenFile, token).then(function(err) {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Token was successfully retrieved and written to " .cyan +
            tokenFile .cyan + "." .cyan);
     });
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code for `callApiToken()`? I suspect you are returning the same promise each time instead of creating a new one.

Comment: I think you also need to change this: `.then(function() { refreshToken(); })` to this: `.then(function() { return refreshToken(); })` so you chain with the other promises in `refreshToken()`

Comment: What is this `block` thing supposed to do???

Comment: `block` is when  there are repeated requests... i'ts triggered by url requests...so it the user refreshes alot the function will only run once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no such thing as a "memory scope". You simply have a timing issue!

If an action is asynchronous, you **always** have to `return` a promise from the function when you want to wait for the result - and you seem to do.

```
var file = {};

function createTokenFile() {
    block = true;
    callApiToken()
        .then(function() {
            return refreshToken();
//          ^^^^^^ here
        })
        .catch(function() {
            return callApiToken();
//          ^^^^^^ and here
        }).finally(function() {
            block = false;
        });
}

function refreshToken() {
    var tokenFileAbsolute = path.join(__dirname, 'token-file.json');
    return fs.readFileAsync(tokenFileAbsolute, {encoding: 'utf-8'})
        .then(function(tokenString) {
            file.token = JSON.parse(tokenString);
        }).catch(function(err) {
            console.log("No token-file.json file found. " .red +
                "Please complete for a new one." .red);
            return createTokenFile();
//          ^^^^^^ and here!!!
        });
}
```

Btw, my guess is that your recursion is flawed. Don't you want `refreshToken` to reject, and `createTokenFile` to call itself from within itself (instead of the second `callApiToken()`)?

Comment: Yep, that was it. I didn't realize `callApiToken` is a function returning a promise...not a promise itself.